# Implementing correct CSP rules for CDN

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mithril.js

I'm currently undertaking a introduction to mobile webapplications development course at my university and am struggling setting up bootstrap on my mithril application.

I've previously set up bootstrap fine on *"normal"* web applications, but I'm struggling understanding how to properly set up Content Security Policy in my Mithril.js application.

It should be noted that this is not a required part of my current assignment, but I'm rather trying to understand the concept of CSP on my own hand since it is a highly important thing to understand (**OWASP top 10**, yo!).

So I'm not asking for anyone to help me finish an assignment or so, rather to help me understand where I'm going wrong with this extra-curricular application of CSP.

---

This is how my CSP looks right now:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval';
         style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css;
         media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;
         script-src https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
         http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js;">
```

The CDN urls work fine and are currently implemented accross multiple other websites I've setup, but I'm getting these errors whilst checking the console on Chrome:

> Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:8013/cordova.js' because
>   it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
>                                                               http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js".
>
> index.html:1 Refused to load the script
>   'http://localhost:8013/bin/app.js' because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
>                                                               http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js".
>
> jquery.min.js:2 Refused to load the font
>   'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'".
>   Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used
>   as a fallback.
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2 jquery.min.js:2 Refused to load the font
>   'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'".
>   Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used
>   as a fallback.
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2 jquery.min.js:2 Refused to load the font
>   'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'".
>   Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used
>   as a fallback.
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2 http://localhost:8013/favicon.ico Failed
>   to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not
>   Found)

Answer (score 1):

Answering this question in our chat as well, but for others here is the short answer. Put your url to the css file in front of 'unsafe-inline', so it is

```
style-src 'self' bootstrap.css 'unsafe-inline';
```

And the you need 'self' in script-src prior to jquery and bootstrap.js.

Comment: This is a horrible idea, as including `'unsafe-inline'` means you might not have CSP at all